# Using WCF to call PHP SOAP service

Tags: c#, php, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have to develop a **.NET API** to a working **php soap service**, but I only have a **WSDL file**, that specifies the service attributes.

When I try to make a Service Reference in Visual Studio with the WSDL file it doesn't work, an **error** occurs:

> "The content type text/plain of the response message does not match
>   the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8).
>   If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported
>   method is implemented properly. "

When I open the WSDL in Visual Studio, intellisense has a problem with <xs:sequence> in <types>, it says: "**Namespace prefix 'xs' is not defined**" - maybe there's something wrong here, but I don't speak WSDL....

Here is the WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<definitions name="ProtopmailApiWorld"
         targetNamespace="urn:ProtopmailApiWorld"
         xmlns:tns="urn:ProtopmailApiWorld"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:API">
        <xsd:complexType name="arrayOfStrings">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TheStringValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="outResponse" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:schema>
</types>

<message name="ApiSoap">
    <part name="params" type="tns:arrayOfStrings" />
</message>
<message name="ApiSoapResponse">
    <part name="return" type="tns:outResponse" />
</message>

<portType name="APIPort">
    <operation name="ApiSoap">
        <input message="tns:ApiSoap" />
        <output message="tns:ApiSoapResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="APIBinding" type="tns:APIPort">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="ApiSoap">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ApiSoapAction" />
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:API" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:API" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name="ApiSoapService">
    <port name="APIPort" binding="tns:APIBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://website/api/soap.php" />
    </port>
</service>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that this WSDL is not valid since the xs prefix is not defined. To fix it add this definition:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

somewhere on the first  tag near the similar definitions.

regardeless I always recommend to first get a sample working soap (maybe from a php client, or the vendor) and then use C#.

EDIT: There were a few more problems with this wsdl - the namespace definition tns was different than the schema target namespace, so I arbitrarly chose one, and also the return type referes to an unknown type, so I changes it to string. try this:

```
<definitions name="ProtopmailApiWorld"
         targetNamespace="urn:ProtopmailApiWorld"
         xmlns:tns="urn:ProtopmailApiWorld"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:ProtopmailApiWorld">
        <xsd:complexType name="arrayOfStrings">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TheStringValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="outResponse" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:schema>
</types>

<message name="ApiSoap">
    <part name="params" type="tns:arrayOfStrings" />
</message>
<message name="ApiSoapResponse">
    <part name="return" type="xsd:string" />
</message>

<portType name="APIPort">
    <operation name="ApiSoap">
        <input message="tns:ApiSoap" />
        <output message="tns:ApiSoapResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="APIBinding" type="tns:APIPort">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="ApiSoap">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ApiSoapAction" />
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:API" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:API" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name="ApiSoapService">
    <port name="APIPort" binding="tns:APIBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://website/api/soap.php" />
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: thanks, now i can add the service reference. but i cannot create any variable to use it, is that even possible to use the php soap service with wcf this way? i mean there is no any endpoint definition here..

Comment: I now see this service is rpc/encoded. I recommend to use .net 2 client and not wcf, e.g. "add web reference" instead of "add service reference"

Comment: here is how to add web service reference http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2008/10/interoperability-gotcha-visual-studio.html

Comment: okay i did that, i called the webservice "ProtopmailWebservice", but i still cannot create any variable with that type (added the namespace correctly)